# Div margins issue for a draggable div

Tags: html, css

I have a div which has its CSS initially defined as:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    bottom: 60px;
    background-color: cyan;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

That is with equal distance from screen borders and I wanted to make it draggable via jQuery. This wouldn't work because of the right and bottom CSS directives.

So my next idea was to use this CSS definition:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    background-color: cyan;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Which according to my understanding would create a div with a width and height equal to 90% of the screen width/height and additionally the margin directives (5% on each side) would position it in the center of the screen.

This solution doesn't seem to work for 100%.

It works horizontally, the div is centered horizontally BUT vertically the space in the bottom is less than the space on top. Which is not what I want it to be.

I know I could use `calc()` to solve it in a different way but I want to avoid it due to browser compatibility (IE8).

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You'll have to specify the height of the parent of this div is. E.g. if its parent is body, you'll have to specify `body{height:100%}`.

Comment: the height of this div was specified as you said, to 100%

Comment: Also you may have to make sure that `body` or `html` don't have any padding or margin besides having them being at 100%

Comment: @d6bels they didn't have any margins or padding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm kind of stupid today.

i removed the margins and used:

```
top: 5%;
left: 5%;
```

and it solved my problem.

Comment: Also make sure your body and html elements have a width and height of 100% set on them, that should solve a number of issues